# Which verb form follows after "Something we can do, is "

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following is correct?

- Something we can do is investigate the effects of...
- Something we can do is investigating the effects of...

I would say it's the first, but based on intuition rather than on grammar - someone I'm writing a text with thinks it's the second.

Can someone explain more formally which form is correct?

*Edit*

Some more context:

*As actual costs are unknown, we cannot test if our model is successful on this basis. Something we can do, however, is investigate the consistency of our model over time. Although the structure...*

These are the opening sentences of a paragraph.

Comment: Can and investigate seem to go together, and you do not need that comma. Investigate is really _to investigate_. _Something we can do_ sounds like one thing or action, not a whole business of _investigating_. More context?

Comment: You have used _do_ in the main clause, so what follows must be the complement of _do_, which requires an infinitive (i.e, _He did eat it_ is OK, but *_He did eating it_ is ungrammatical). Since _investigate_ is an infinitive and _investigating_ is not an infinitive, the first one is correct and the second isn't. (I bet it's the same in Nederlandse).

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I added some more context, I guess in the "true" form the comma's are necessary.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Interesting, because intuitively I would have said it should be infinitive because you would say _"we can investigate"_. Thanks for your explanation. In Dutch in this case the forms are actually indistinguishable so I can't tell which I would need :)

Comment: @JohnLawler That sorta makes sense, but I have this one way of thinking about it that confuses me. That is, the sentence resembles the form X is Y. One could say *Playing is a good thing* in which we are linking a gerund to a noun phrase. Isn't this the same thing? Or does the presence of the verb *do* really throw things off?

Comment: The sentence is [a special construction called a "Cleft" sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+cleft). This one uses _something_, others use _it_ or _what_. It's basically one transformation of _However, we can investigate the consistency ..._ Others might start _One thing we can do_ or _What we can do_. The _do is_ gets inserted by the transformation; it's an infinitive because _can_ requires an infinitive. Like _do_.

Comment: When you insert _however_, the commas become helpful because of the insertion, not because one or two would be needed otherwise.

Comment: You are right. "Something we can do" is a noun phrase headed by "something" with the relative clause "we can do" as modifier. The infinitival clause "(to) investigate the effects of ..." is predicative complement  of "be" in its specifying sense. The object of "do" is missing, but is understood as "something". Your other example with "investigating" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

"Investigate" would be right in this sentence. This may not be the conventional way of doing it, but what I usually do in this situation is, strip the first verb "do" and the unnecessary word, like "something" (I'm doing it in this sentence right here, stripping off the "what" and "do"). Your sentence then reads:

> We can ---- the effects of..

and the right word there would be "investigate" and not "investigating"

My sentence "what I usually do in this situation is, strip the first part of the verb and the unnecessary word" when stripped, would read:

> I usually ---- the first verb..

and the right word here would be "strip" and not "stripping"

Answer (score -3):

Investigating or in the other word second one, because we need a noun form after is,and one of the noun making ways is adding ing.

Comment: It seems the answers in the comments disagree with you. But thanks for your response!